# Check if an app already exists in Android market via API

Tags: android, google-play

This Android market API has a method `isInMarket()`. Can I use this method to check if an app already exists in the Android market?

```
AppInfo mAppInfo = new AppInfo("packagename.example");
if (!mAppInfo.isInMarket()) {
    //app non-exist in the android market
} 
else {
    //app exist in the android market
}
```

I tested this code in an emulator but it doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Comment: Can I ask which Android market API you are using?

Comment: I would pretty much know which API you're using, because I'm trying to find it like crazy but have been unable to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The android emulator does not have the market app installed in it so the framework wont work.  The web-android-market-api requires that you have the android market app installed.

Here is a link on [how to install market](http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html) onto the emulator

Comment: Thank for your answer. 
Then you think my code that it work or not??

Comment: yes.
You can also install market into your emulator and test it.
See [here on how to do](http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html) that on the emulator